# C++. SevenZip compression to zip format. ClassFactory cannot supply requested class

Tags: c++, 7zip

I have a problem with SevenZip library. I'm trying to compress files using zip format and gets error (exception) on creating object - "CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE ClassFactory cannot supply requested class".

Code looks like this:

```
std::wstring CSevenZipManager::CompressAllFiles( const wchar_t* szSourcePath, const wchar_t* szDestinationPath, void (*UpdateProgressBar)( int, void* ), void* pUserData, SevenZip::CompressionFormatEnum eCompressionFormat /*= SevenZip::CompressionFormat::SevenZip*/ )
{
    SevenZip::SevenZipLibrary lib;
    std::wstring oError;

    try
    {
        lib.Load(_T("7za.dll"));

        SevenZip::SevenZipCompressor compressor( lib, szDestinationPath );
        compressor.SetCompressionFormat( eCompressionFormat );
        compressor.CompressAllFiles( szSourcePath, true, UpdateProgressBar, pUserData );
    }
    catch( SevenZip::SevenZipException oEx )
    {
        oError = oEx.GetMessage();
    }

    lib.Free();

    return oError;
}
```

Then from compressor.CompressAllFiles program goes (not directly, but between nothing important happens) to:

```
void SevenZipCompressor::CompressFilesToArchive( const TString& pathPrefix, const std::vector< FilePathInfo >& filePaths, int* pPrecent, void (*UpdateProgressBar)( int, void* ), void* pUserData, int* piThreadNumber )
{
    CComPtr< IOutArchive > archiver = GetArchiveWriter(m_library, m_compressionFormat);

    unsigned long long int uiDirSize = 0;

...
```

And in GetArchiveWriter I have:

```
CComPtr< IOutArchive > GetArchiveWriter(const SevenZipLibrary& library, const CompressionFormatEnum& format)
{
   const GUID* guid = NULL;

   switch (format)
   {
   case CompressionFormat::Zip:
      guid = &CLSID_CFormatZip;
      break;

   case CompressionFormat::GZip:
      guid = &CLSID_CFormatGZip;
      break;

   case CompressionFormat::BZip2:
      guid = &CLSID_CFormatBZip2;
      break;

   case CompressionFormat::Rar:
      guid = &CLSID_CFormatRar;
      break;

   case CompressionFormat::Tar:
      guid = &CLSID_CFormatTar;
      break;

   case CompressionFormat::Iso:
      guid = &CLSID_CFormatIso;
      break;

   case CompressionFormat::Cab:
      guid = &CLSID_CFormatCab;
      break;

   case CompressionFormat::Lzma:
      guid = &CLSID_CFormatLzma;
      break;

   case CompressionFormat::Lzma86:
      guid = &CLSID_CFormatLzma86;
      break;

   default:
      guid = &CLSID_CFormat7z;
      break;
   }

   CComPtr< IOutArchive > archive;
   library.CreateObject(*guid, IID_IOutArchive, reinterpret_cast< void** >(&archive));
   return archive;
}
```

Where CLSID_CFormatZip looks like:

```
DEFINE_GUID(CLSID_CFormatZip,
    0x23170F69, 0x40C1, 0x278A, 0x10, 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x10, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00);
```

And when zip or any other format is selected I get "CLASS_E_CLASSNOTAVAILABLE ClassFactory cannot supply requested class" on library.CreateObject(*guid, IID_IOutArchive, reinterpret_cast< void** >(&archive)). Only default option - 7z format - works. Object is created. What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Solution is simple - I didn't use full 7z.dll, but smaller one, that only was able to compress to 7z format.